# Is there a way to set a AWS Oracle RDS to be case insensitive for data joins?

Tags: amazon-web-services, oracle, amazon-rds

I could have sworn there was a way to do this but I have not been able to find any documentation on it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You mean, so that e.g. `where 'user68288' = 'USeR68288'` returns *true*? If so, well - I don't use AWS, but - if simple `where lower('user68288') = lower('USeR68288')` helps, good. I'd expect it to actually perform *worse* because of possible indexes on columns involved unless you create function-based index. On the other hand, if that's some *setting* within the AWS, no idea - I hope someone else will know it.

Comment: There's nothing special about *settings* within AWS vs. using Oracle database anywhere else. You won't find documentation for this because there isn't any. If you need a join to be case-insensitive, you'd need to do as @Littlefoot suggests and use an embedded function to force one or both columns - depending on the nature of the source data - to be all upper or all lower case in the join comparison.